# Bootstrap Tab Pane slide effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

OK, pretty self-explanatory but I cannot figure how it's done, nor can I find any resources...

I have simple list of `tab-pane`s like :

```
  tab-pane fade in active
```

But I do not need a `fade` transition. But a `slide` one, instead, preferably from the right. Is there such a thing? How can I do it?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Sebsemillia It's 3.2.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created that little js function:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {    
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $(target).css('left','-'+$(window).width()+'px');   
    var left = $(target).offset().left;
    $(target).css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0px"}, "10");
})
```

You just have to add this small CSS to the standard Bootstrap, the standard HTML markup stays the same:

```
.tab-content .tab-pane {    
    position: relative;
}
```

Take a look at this bootply to see if it is what you want.

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/WNgHeijnsJ)

Comment: how about sliding left/right (according to the position of the tab) without fade at all? current slides out, new slides in.