# How to give the slide up /slide down effect to bootstrap tab-pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have got the basic tab of bootstrap and i want when i change the tab menu the content (tab-pane) should animate like bootstrap collapse does( slide down/slide up)
Is it possible ?

```
<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">This Is good</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">This is better</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Thhis is excellent </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">This is poor</div>
</div>
```

I'm running out of idea so please help me i know it's a silly question.

Here is the [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hjuuf0f5/)

Comment: use animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Have you used bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 3...?

Comment: Sorry I haven't mentioned .I'm using bootstrap 4 alpha

Comment: @UpendraJoshi i'm really running out of idea would you please give me 5 line code so that i could understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Tab Pane slide effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719382/bootstrap-tab-pane-slide-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. I have added some js for sliding effect.

```js
$('.tabs').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {     
  if (e.relatedTarget === undefined) {    
    $($(e.target).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
  }
  else {
    $($(e.relatedTarget).attr('href')).slideUp({ duration: 'fast', queue: true,
      done: function() {
        $($(e.target).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

```css
.tab-pane{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:20px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="tabs">
<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel"  style="display: block;"><p>This Is good</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="profile" role="tabpanel"  style="display: none;"><p>This is better</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="messages" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;"><p>Thhis is excellent</p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="settings" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;"><p>This is poor</p></div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that perfect but i want the tab-pane box to be animated like this not the content of the tab

Comment: @Tanmay , I think you want like this...? pls check I have updated some code.

Comment: have you ever looked at bootstrap collapse system ?
I want the tab-pane should slide up slide sown and the content remain fixed..Just want the features of collapse system's animation

Comment: @Tanmay, I know how bootstrap tab work , but in bootstrap there is fade effect so you don't recognize that whole tab-pane(including text) had effect  contain do not remain fixed.

Comment: Though i'm not satisfied but your answer may help someone

Comment: i wanted this kinda effect http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Collapsible-Panel-Plugin/

Answer (score 1):

First download animate.css and add it to code. Lastly give class to tab-content

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active  animated bounceInDown" id="home" role="tabpanel">This Is good</div>
          <div class="tab-pane  animated bounceInDown" id="profile" role="tabpanel">This is better</div>
          <div class="tab-pane  animated bounceInDown" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Thhis is excellent </div>
          <div class="tab-pane  animated bounceInDown" id="settings" role="tabpanel">This is poor</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $($(e.target).attr('href')).hide()
})
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $($(e.target).attr('href')).slideDown()
})
```